# How can I run command which has it own options in node child process exec

Tags: javascript, node.js, command-line-interface

I am creating make node CLI automate my npm package publishing, I am struck by this problem. After all Confirmation, I want to run the command `semantic-release` but problem it has its own prompts
I currently use exec command but It does not show any prompts created by  `semantic-release`

Code

```js
const timer = showLoading(`running ${chalk.blue(command)} `);
exec(command, (error, stdout, stderr) => {
                process.stdout.write(chalk.dim(`\r running ${chalk.blue(command)}   `));
                clearInterval(timer);
                defaults.onFinish();
                if (error) {
                    defaults.onError(error);
                    console.log(error);
                }
                defaults.onSuccess(stdout);
                console.log(stdout);
            });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can show the prompts by spawning a synchronous child process that inherits it's [`stdio`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#optionsstdio) pipes from the parent process.

#### JS :

```js
import { spawnSync } from 'child_process';
let { status } = spawnSync('./test.sh', [], { stdio: 'inherit' });
if (status > 0) { throw new Error('spawned process exited abnormally'); }
```

#### test.sh

```bash
#!/bin/bash
read -p 'enter something: ' value
[ -z "$value" ] && exit 1
echo "$value"
```

Answer (score -1):

I have used this way to create my own `CLI`, it's an easy way to create all the commands that I want and to do what I want, check the link maybe that helps you, in the website there also good explanation with images

[Click here](https://dev.to/rushankhan1/build-a-cli-with-node-js-4jbi)

Comment: Thanks but it does not show how to run command

Comment: Please post the easy way and the explanation in your answer, not just a link an external resource.